# Define array of objects based on a mongoose schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema in mongoose that I would like to have as a nested array in another schema:

```
var NestedSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Some other schema that needs and array of the nested schema.

```
var EventSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  fields: [NestedSchema]
});
```

Which works just fine.  However now I want to run some validation against that array.

```
var validators = // some validators
var EventSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  fields: [{ type: 'NestedSchema', required: true, validate: validators }]
});
```

Of course type: 'NestedSchema' does not work, it was a shoot in the dark.  Does mongoose allow you to have an array of object based on schema

Answer (score 0):

Using: 
   MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12,
   Mongoose : 4.4.7

I managed to have an array based on schema that way:

```
var NestedSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});

var EventSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  fields: [{ type: [NestedSchema], required: true }]
});
```

Did not try validation, but I believe it will work as required works well. :)

Comment: TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at array `fields`